# Possible bug in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I have a Firebase storage bucket that has the default security rules, only authenticated users can upload their files to the bucket. But this security rule seems to only apply when my web application when it is being viewed from my laptop and I am actually able to upload data and files to Firebase database and storage bucket without logging in on my phone. Is this a bug?

Because when I upload a file from my laptop, without logging in it says:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'images/wppr.jpg'.

This prevents the upload of files and data to the database and the storage bucket, only on my laptop. **Not on my phone**.

Same application. Same security rules. Two different devices and two separate behaviors.

**EDIT**

I did not change the security rules on my Firebase storage project. This is how it happened, I kept some UI which the user can use to upload some files to Firebase storage but only if they are logged in. This worked on my laptop but not on my phone. This only happened when I log in, upload some files, then exit the web app without logging out and then when I go back into my web app, the onAuthChanged  function displays UI that should be displayed when a user is logged out (implying that I am not logged in), **but** I can upload files successfully. This does not happen when I log in, upload files, log out and then try to upload some files without logging in.

**EDIT 2**

I have also found this to happen when I refresh the web app on my laptop without logging out. I am able to upload files. Why is this happening?

Comment: Keep in mind: it takes up to five minutes from when you change the security rules on your Firebase Storage project until they are applied. If that's not the problem, you'll have to share some more information on how we can reproduce the problem you're having. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Take a look at the edit to see how this happened.